# Oracle- Multiple rows in single row with adding column of duplicate value

Tags: oracle

```
Id Field_id Field_value
------------------------------
1   10           'A'
1   11           'B'
1   12           'C'
```

I want to make rows like

```
Id Field_id Field_value data_1  data_2
--------------------------------------
1   10           'A'     'B'     'C'
```

Pl help.

Comment: How are they duplicates ? Field_Id is different...

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. With any SQL question, please provide test case, which includes, create statements, few insert statements as sample data and desired output.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at this:

```
with t (Id, Field_id, Field_value) as (
  select 1, 10, 'A' from dual union all
  select 1, 11, 'B' from dual union all
  select 1, 12, 'C' from dual
)
select FIELD_ID1, "10_FIELD_ID", "11_FIELD_ID","12_FIELD_ID"
  from (select id, field_id, min(field_id) over() field_id1, field_value from t)
 pivot (
  max(field_value) field_id
  for field_id in (10, 11, 12)
)

FIELD_ID1   10_FIELD_ID 11_FIELD_ID 12_FIELD_ID
---------------------------------------------------
       10        A           B           C
```

Read more about pivot [here](http://diefororacle.blogspot.ru/2014/08/pivot-sql-extenssion-for-oracle-database.html)

Comment: here in post I wrote 1 as ID, but that could be any number.. I mean the Id is not predefined.

Comment: It doesn't matter. you can exclude this ID if you want. see my rewritten post

Comment: @zaratustra,  vote up from my side. Nice...you have demonstrated that PIVOT is one of the possible solutions. Very nice :-) I would be concerned with the `IN` list, as it would scan the table for each value in the IN list. Isn't it?

Comment: @LalitKumarB In the worst case PIVOT will perform only one full scan of the table if there is no indexes. If the table has indexes then it can scan only one index to get the result set. I know it because I am preparing an article about improving of PIVOT operations.

Comment: @zaratustra, good to know, I would be keen to read your article. All the best, and do send me a link.

Answer (score 0):

Normally, people look for PIVOT query, however, your input data is not at all duplicate as already mentioned in comments.

What you could do is, using subquery factoring, `select id, 10 as field_id, field_value`, thus making field_it static value as 10. Then use `LISTAGG`. But, the grouped rows would be a single column as delimeter seperated values.

I hope your requirement is exactly what you stated and not a typo or a mistake while posting.

Comment: There is no answer in your post. If I got it right, the OP needs to have three separated columns

Comment: I am very new to database. post is a simpler version of my requirement. here id is a key. In post Id is reapeated, on the basis of Id I need to identify the duplicate row and create a single row with adding values from the duplicate rows.

Comment: As I mentioned, PIVOT is an usual requirement. However, OP might not be clear with his requirement. So, a benifit of doubt can be considered for him. If OP is fine with single column, LISTAGG could be a good option. Else, based on field_id, OP could use PIVOT, but lot of coding for each value.

Comment: @Anil, Read my comment in your post. Please post the required details, either I or someone could assist you. If required, I will update my answer to suit your requirement.

Comment: Can anybody write the simple (pivot or LISTAGG )code for the same and exmplain?

Comment: @AnilGavate see my post.